# Cusps in the Compactification of Modular Curves $Y(\Gamma)$

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

I'm currently reading some of the geometric theory behind the theory of modular forms, Diamond and Shurman's book is my main reference. If $\Gamma$ is a congruence subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, the modular curve $Y(\Gamma)$ is defined to be the quotient $\Gamma \backslash \mathfrak{H}$. In order to compactify this curve one needs to add a finite number of cusps $s_1,\dots, s_n$ which are the distinct orbits of $\Gamma$ acting on $\mathbb{Q}\cup \{ \infty\}$.

The case where $\Gamma=SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ makes sense to me since the group acts transivity on $\mathbb{Q}\cup \infty$, but for general $\Gamma$, why do we need to add in the other orbits (apart from the orbit containing $\infty$) in order to compactify the curve?

A somewhat related question: Diamond and Shurman describe a modular form of weight $k$ for $\Gamma$ as being holomorphic at the "limit points" and yet I cannot find any other reference to this idea. How does one realize these cusps as "limit points"?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you leave out one of the orbits, then you won't end up with a compact space. The complements of closures of a sequence of neighborhoods of the missing orbit form an open cover without a finite subcover. The images of [the fundamental domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain) under $\Gamma$ reach as close to all of $\Bbb{Q}$ as you wish. In other words, all the rational points occur as vertices of triangular regions in that image.

Comment: I think the idea is the following. You have a local parameter at all the cusps that you can use to study functions near them (e.g. whether they are holomorphic there). You get one from a local parameter $q=e^{2\pi i z}$ at $i\infty$ by mapping it to any cusp by an action of $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$. Doing it this way then gives a well defined local parameter for all the cusps in $\Gamma\backslash\mathfrak{H}$ (for any subgroup $\Gamma$).

Comment: May be a more familiar case of using a local parameter is that of the Riemann sphere. A function $f(z)$ is holomorphic (resp. has a pole of a finite order) at $z=z_0\neq\infty$, if it can be written locally as a power series of the local parameter $q=z-z_0$ (resp. together with a finite linear combination of powers of $1/q$. When you study a function near the point $z=\infty$ you use the local parameter $1/z$. A local parameter is needed (and comes together with) for the object to have a structure of a Riemann surface.

Comment: So, if $s = \alpha(\infty)$ for some $\alpha\in SL_2(Z)\backslash \Gamma$, then the neighbourhoods of $\infty$,  $\mathcal{N}_M = \{z\in \mathfrak{H}| \Im(z)>M \}$, map to neighbourhoods of $s$ under $\alpha$. I.e., these are the the sequence of neighbourhoods of $s$ that form a open covering without a finite subcover.

Do you have an easy way to see that these neighbourhoods are contained in the fundamental domain for $\Gamma$?

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you might find this elementary example helpful:

For $ p $ a prime, the modular curve $ X_{0}(p) = \mathcal{H} / \Gamma_{0} $
has two cusps on $ \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{Q}) $ which can be denoted by
$ [1,0] $ and $ [0,1] $. To see this, we partition rational numbers $ \mathbb{Q} $ as $ \{ t \in \mathbb{Q} : p|deno(t) \} \cup 
(\{ t \in \mathbb{Q}: p \not | deno(t) \} \backslash \{ 0 \})  $.
Here by $ deno(t) $ I meant denominator of t.

For the first set, let $ r = u/v $ where $ p | v $. Because of the irreducibility of the representation of $ r $, there must be $ c, d \in \mathbb{Z} $ such that $ cu - dv = 1 $. The matrix $ M=(-c,d;v,-u) \in \Gamma_{0}$ takes $ r $ to $ \infty $, i.e.,
$ \frac {-cr + d}{vr - u} = \infty $. Similarly for a given $ s = u/v $ you can always find a matrix in $ \Gamma_{0} $ taking $ \infty $ to $ s $.

For the second set, let $ r = u/v $ where $ p \not |v $. From $ gcd(u,v)=1$
and $ gcd(p,v)=1 $ we have that $ gcd(v, pu)=1 $ therefore, we have another
determinant-form expression $ cpu - dv = 1 $ for some $ c,d \in \mathbb{Z} $.
The matrix $ M=(v,-u;cp,-d) \in \Gamma_{0} $ is the matrix taking $ r $ to zero
and similarly for a given $ s=u/v $ you can find a matrix in $ \Gamma_{0} $ taking a given $ 0 $ to $ s $. it simply shows that the modular curve $ X_{0}(p) $ for a prime number $ p $ has two cusps which can be roughly represented by $ 0 $ and $ \infty $.